# jQuery Ajax Request without loading results

Tags: jquery

Hey all, i'm really new to ajax and all i want to do is call an ajax function that doesn't return anything. I've used

$('#myDiv').load('/ajaxScript.asp');

and that loads the results to myDiv just fine. I just want to run the ajax without returning anything at all. Just run my code. How do i do this? Also, how do i detect when it is done doing it's thing? Thanks all!

Comment: You could just specify a non-existant DIV or load into a hidden DIV. (I am pretty sure.)

Comment: Flipper, that's a bad suggestion. It's hackish! Always look for alternatives; chances are there's one made.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the simple functions:

```
jQuery.post("{url}", {parameters}, function(data, status){}, "text");
```

or

```
jQuery.get("{url}", {parameters}, function(data, status){}, "text");
```

See http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/ or http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/. The function will get called when the request returns.

Comment: THat is awesome! Seemed to work fine. Is there a way that i can say when onComplete do this? I know in prototype you do something like new Ajax.Request('page.html', {onComplete:function(){}});

Comment: The function gets called when the request is complete, so just put your logic in there. For example: `jQuery.post("{url}", {parameters}, function(data, status){ alert("COMPLETE"); }, "text");` will do it.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `$.ajax` instead of load; which is basically an alias of $(receiver).load();

Documentation here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Demo code here:

```
$.ajax({
  url: '/path/to/file',
  type: 'POST',
  dataType: 'xml/html/script/json/jsonp',
  data: {param1: 'value1'},
  complete: function(xhr, textStatus) {
    //called when complete
  },
  success: function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
    //called when successful
  },
  error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    //called when there is an error
  }
});
```